# Space of a fixed size between word and number in theorems

Tags: spacing, environments, amsmath, theorems

I am using some commands in the document to prevent LaTeX from word breaking:

```
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
```

I also define new theorem-like environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt,
spacebelow=6pt,
headindent=0pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries,
notebraces={(}{)},
headpunct=.,
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
postheadspace=1em,
%qed=\qedsymbol
]{THEOREMstyle}

\declaretheorem[%
style=THEOREMstyle,%
parent=section,%
name=\normalfont\bfseries Theorem%
]{Theorem}
```

The problem is the following: sometimes TeX stretches the space between the word "Theorem" and the number, so it looks like

```
Theorem                  1.1.1          Text --------
```

Can I somehow specify the space length, so it will always look like

```
Theorem 1.1.1. And       here         the       stretching       of        the      text       is           allowed
```

**UPDATE.** Here is a part of code (should be compiled with Lua- or XeLaTeX) to show the problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paperheight=8.27in,
paperwidth=5.85in,
top=0.8in,
bottom=0.8in,
outer=0.5in, 
inner=1in,
voffset=0in,
%footskip=2em
marginparwidth=0.5in,
marginparsep=0.2in
}
%
\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textfrak{\alphalph{\value{footnote}}}}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
%\fancypagestyle{A}{
%  \fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead[RO]{\ifthenelse{\value{chapter}=0}{}{\textsl{\thesubsection. \Subsectiontitle}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textsl{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\ifthenelse{\value{chapter}=0}{}{\textsl{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[CE]{}
\fancyhead[CO]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
%}

\renewcommand\footrule{\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize height 2pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize   
\end{minipage}\par}%


\renewcommand\headrule{\vspace{-5pt}
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize height 2pt 
\end{minipage}}%


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[RO,RE,LE,LO,CO,CE]{}
  \fancyfoot[RO,LE,RE,LO]{}

  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ из \pageref{LastPage}}%

\renewcommand\footrule{\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize height 2pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize   
\end{minipage}\par}%

\renewcommand\headrule{}%

}

\pagestyle{fancy}


%
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\newcommand{\Subsectiontitle}{}
\newcommand{\Subsection}[1]{\subsection{#1}\renewcommand{\Subsectiontitle}{\uppercase{#1}}}



\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.5em}


\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{skull}
\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage{xfrac} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
%
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   
\setmainlanguage{russian}




\newcommand{\TT}{\item[]}
\newcommand{\HA}{\item[${}^{\bigstar}$]}
\newcommand{\HH}{\item[${}^{\skull}$]}
\newcommand{\BO}{\item[${}^{\includegraphics[height=6pt]{accordion.png}}$]}

\newcounter{qcounter}%local counter for QUESTIONS environment 
\newcounter{subqcounter}
\newcounter{enumercounter}
\newcounter{tmp} %counter that is the number of the last task
\newcounter{pageend} %counter that is the number of first task
\setcounter{tmp}{0}
\setcounter{pageend}{-1}
\newcounter{NAME}
\setcounter{NAME}{1}
\renewcommand{\theNAME}{\Alph{NAME}}

\newenvironment{questions}{
    \begin{list}{ 
        \bfseries\upshape\arabic{qcounter}.
    }{
        \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{%
    \textbf{\refstepcounter{qcounter}\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{qcounter}##1.}}%
        \usecounter{qcounter}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{2em}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep+0.5em}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}
            \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
        \setlength{\parsep}{1pt}
        \setlength{\topsep}{6pt}
    } 
}{    
    \end{list}
}

\newenvironment{subquestions}{
    \begin{list}{ 
        \bfseries(\roman{subqcounter})
    }{
        \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{%
    \textbf{\refstepcounter{subqcounter}(\roman{subqcounter}##1)}}%
        \usecounter{subqcounter}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{2.5em}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep+0.5em}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
            \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
        \setlength{\parsep}{1pt}
        \setlength{\topsep}{1pt}
    } 
}{    
    \end{list}
}

\newenvironment{enumer}{
    \begin{list}{ 
        \bfseries(\roman{enumercounter})
    }{
        \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{%
    \textbf{\refstepcounter{enumercounter}\Roman{enumercounter}##1.}}%
        \usecounter{enumercounter}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{2em}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep+0.5em}
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{0em}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{3pt}
            \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
        \setlength{\parsep}{1pt}
        \setlength{\topsep}{2pt}
    } 
}{    
    \end{list}
}


\newcommand{\sep}{\vspace{3pt}\hrule\vspace{3pt}}
\newcommand{\bb}[1]{$#1\times#1$}
\newcommand{\bbb}[2]{$#1\times#2$}

\newcommand{\EX}[2]{
\begin{exercise}
#1 \textbf{Ответ:} \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{#2}.
\end{exercise}
}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt,
spacebelow=6pt,
headindent=0pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries,
notebraces={(}{)},
headpunct=.,
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
postheadspace=1em,
%qed=\qedsymbol
]{THEOREMstyle}

\declaretheorem[%
style=THEOREMstyle,%
parent=section,%
%parent=subparagraph,
name=\normalfont\bfseries Теорема%
]{Theorem}

\declaretheorem[%
style=THEOREMstyle,%
%parent=section,%
sibling=Theorem,%
name=\normalfont\bfseries Лемма%
]{Lemma}

\declaretheorem[%
style=THEOREMstyle,%
%parent=section,%
sibling=Theorem,%
name=\normalfont\bfseries Утверждение%
]{Statement}

\declaretheorem[%
style=THEOREMstyle,%
%parent=section,%
sibling=Theorem,%
name=\normalfont\bfseries Предложение%
]{Proposition}

\declaretheorem[%
style=THEOREMstyle,%
parent=Theorem,%
name=\normalfont\bfseries Следствие%
]{Corollary}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt,
spacebelow=6pt,
headindent=0pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries,
notebraces={(}{)},
headpunct=.,
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
%qed=\qedsymbol
]{DEFINITIONstyle}

\declaretheorem[%
style=DEFINITIONstyle,%
parent=section,%
name=\normalfont\bfseries  Определение%
]{Definition}

\declaretheorem[%
style=DEFINITIONstyle,%
numbered=no,%
name=\normalfont\bfseries  Замечание%
]{Remark}

\declaretheorem[%
style=DEFINITIONstyle,%
parent=chapter,%
name=\normalfont\bfseries  Упражнение%
]{Exercise}

\declaretheorem[%
style=DEFINITIONstyle,%
parent=chapter,%
name=\normalfont\bfseries  Пример%
]{Example}

\newcommand{\EXER}[2]{
\begin{Exercise}
#1 \noindent\textbf{Ответ:} \noindent\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{#2}.
\end{Exercise}
}

\newcommand{\BTH}{\begin{Theorem}}
\newcommand{\ETH}{\end{Theorem}}

\newcommand{\BLM}{\begin{Lemma}}
\newcommand{\ELM}{\end{Lemma}}

\newcommand{\BPR}{\begin{Proposition}}
\newcommand{\EPR}{\end{Proposition}}

\newcommand{\BST}{\begin{Statement}}
\newcommand{\EST}{\end{Statement}}

\newcommand{\BCR}{\begin{Corollary}}
\newcommand{\ECR}{\end{Corollary}}

\newcommand{\BDF}{\begin{Definition}}
\newcommand{\EDF}{\end{Definition}}

\newcommand{\BEX}{\begin{Example}}
\newcommand{\EEX}{\end{Example}}

\newcommand{\BRM}{\begin{Remark}}
\newcommand{\ERM}{\end{Remark}}

\newcommand{\QUESTIONSB}{\begin{questions}\setcounter{qcounter}{\value{tmp}}}
\newcommand{\QUESTIONSE}{\setcounter{tmp}{\value{qcounter}}\end{questions}}

\newcommand{\TITLE}[3]{
\title{\Huge #1}
\date{#2}
\author{#3}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
}
\newcommand{\IMG}[2]
{%
\setlength{\columnsep}{2pt}%
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{#1}
\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}
\end{wrapfigure}

}%

%\begin{document}ааа\end{document}

\begin{document}

\BDF
Назовём систему функций замкнутым классом, если любая композиция функций из этой системы является функцией из этой системы.
Например, $P_2$ --- замкнутый класс.
\EDF

\BDF
Система функций $B$ называется базисом в замкнутом классе $F$, если $[B]=F$, причём никакую функцию из $B$ нельзя убрать, чтобы условие сохранилось. 
\EDF

\BDF
Система функций $B$ называется базисом в замкнутом классе $F$, если $[B]=F$, причём никакая функция из $B$ не выражается через другие.
\EDF

\end{document}
```

Comment: hate to say it, but this is a case for rewriting ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton rewriting what?

Comment: do you really want the settings you show at the start? the first two lines already say that you would prefer excessive white space stretching to anything else, so after that really there is no hope of getting reasonable typeset output.

Comment: That said if you fix the example so we can run it and produce the effect shown it should be easy enough to tweak the settings to do what you ask.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I write in Russian and hyphenation should be avoided. By the norms we have, it is more acceptable to have big spaces than hyphention. There are a lot of long words in Russian and if you don't stretch the spaces you will get almost every line hyphenated.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann so not like the example line you give with average word length of 4 letters:-)

Comment: The example code just produces `! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \declaretheoremstyle`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Updated the question with the code

Comment: @MichaelFreimann -- rewriting the text so that there aren't so many long (not-to-be-hyphenated) words.  irregular spaces make text hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unlike glue, kerns never stretch

[image]

```
\declaretheorem[%
style=DEFINITIONstyle,%
parent=section,%
name=\normalfont\bfseries  Определение\kern.2em\ignorespaces%
]{Definition}
```

Comment: Thanx! I've never heard of `\kern`.